# How loadNibNamed function set an IBOutlet property of an UIController

Tags: ios, objective-c, lazy-initialization

Really new to iOS programming and read some codes in tutorial that really confused.

```
-(UIView*)headerView{

    if(!_headerView) {
        [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"HeaderView1" owner:self options:nil];
    }

    return _headerView;
}
```

headerView is a property of a UITableViewController. I suppose original Nib filename 'HeaderView' suggests link to property thus I change it to 'HeaderView1', but it still WORKs.

I don't see explicit assignment to the property like '_headerView=[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed.....];'...and neither implicit association... How such property is set to view initialed by Nib file?

Comment: The "file's owner" is set in the nib to the view controller and there are connections from the view to file's owner.  When you call `loadNibNamed:` the thing you pass to the `owner` parameter has its properties set to what they are connected to in the nib.

Comment: My point is how `loadNibNamed:` knows which property of owner should  be set to Nib file if  there are multiple UIView properties in owner file?

Comment: You make the connections in the nib file to specific properties in the view controller and it sets those ones

Comment: Thanks Dan, saw connection...forget about it....^_^